# How to implement a working Graphql query in Vue with Apollo?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, apollo, vue-apollo

Could someone please help me in getting my first queries working with scaphold.io?

When I query the following to my scaphold, using the internal GraphiQL:

```
query AllPrograms {
  viewer {
    allPrograms{
      edges {
        node {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The return looks like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "viewer": {
      "allPrograms": {
        "edges": [
          {
            "node": {
              "id": "UHJvZ3JhbTo2",
              "name": "Blender"
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "id": "UHJvZ3JhbTo1",
              "name": "Inkscape"
            }
          },

          ...
```

My component looks like this:

```
<template>
  <md-card>
    <span class="md-headline">Programma's</span>
    <span class="md-headline">{{ allPrograms }}</span>
  </md-card>
</template>


<script>
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import config from '../../config/client'

const log = console.log

const allPrograms = gql `
  query AllPrograms {
    viewer {
      allPrograms{
        edges {
          node {
            id
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

export default {
  props: [],
  data () {
    return {
      allPrograms: '',
    }
  },
  // Apollo GraphQL
  apollo: {
    // Local state 'posts' data will be updated
    // by the GraphQL query result
    allPrograms: { // <-- THIS allPrograms IS THE CAUSE OF THE ERROR!
      // GraphQL query
      query: allPrograms,
      // Will update the 'loading' attribute
      // +1 when a new query is loading
      // -1 when a query is completed
      loadingKey: 'loading',
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

The error I get says: **Missing allPrograms attribute on result**

And I also read something that looks like it is part of the correct json-result: `object: viewer: {allPrograms: Object, __typename: "Viewer"}`

Or maybe I am misunderstanding something. I think I am close in receiving the data, might have even succeeded already, but the splitting up seems to need some extra care.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try naming "allPrograms" something else? I don't have much Vue-appolo experience but you have a variable and an appolo property named allPrograms, which may make a weird behavior.

Comment: Doesn't remove the error, but thanks to your suggestion I now know that it's the declaration of `allPrograms` in the `apollo:` part that is the cause of the **Missing allPrograms attribute on result**  error. (Marked it with a comment.) What does this mean? Am I not initialising or resolving it correctly?

Answer (score 6):

It seems `vue-apollo` expects to find under `data` in the response sent by the server a key matching what you set in your apollo definition. Try replacing

```
apollo: {
   allPrograms: { ... }
}
```

by

```
apollo: {
   viewer: { ... }
}
```

and your error goes away, but that's probably not what you want.

Instead, add an `update` option to your query definition to alter the data set. Assuming you want the content of `allPrograms`:

```
apollo: {
    allPrograms: {
        query: allPrograms,
        loadingKey: 'loading',
        update: function(data) {
            return data.viewer.allPrograms;

            // or if you just want the leaf objects
            return data.viewer.allPrograms.edges.map(function(edge) {
                return edge.node;
            });
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: It works, I retrieve json now with return `data.viewer.allPrograms.edges`. The shape of it is `[ { "node": { "id": "UHJvZ3JhbTo2", "name": "Blender", "__typename": "Program" }, "__typename": "ProgramEdge" }, { "node": { "id": "UHJvZ3JhbTo1", "name": "Inkscape", "__typename": "Program" }, "__typename": "ProgramEdge" }, ...`. How to filter it down to only {"id": ..., "name": ...}? Or stop overfetching. Any ideas for that would be welcome, I'll award you the bounty of course.

Comment: I am also getting a 404 (Not Found) error. Not sure if it was there before.

Comment: @Code-MonKy I've added a remapping of the data. To avoid traversing the data, you could setup a new query server-side resolving to just what you want but you'll have to dig in scaphold.io to see how you can do that. As for the 404 error, I'm afraid that's probably from somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out later. Yep, I'll have to dig a little further in scaphold's docs when I want to clean up the result. I am sure the over-fetching is addressed there. Anyway, good stuff for fast prototyping for a beautiful interface.